# invalid number, when no invalid number

Tags: numbers, substring, oracle-sqldeveloper

having an issue with Oracle throwing the error

> ORA-01722: invalid number
>   01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
>   *Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
>   *Action:   Specify a valid number.

all locations follow the same rules, aside from a few abnormalities which have been excluded.

below is sample output:

[image]

Column A: being the row must be less than 39

Column B: being the height must be less than 17

Location_23_23 being the isle

some locations have a different design so ive added a '-' check at position 6 to eliminate those. ex (C0S1-0101)

ive exported the data and no abnormalities are found, but when scrolling through the results the error occurs.

code below:

```
select location_id,to_number(ltrim(rtrim(substr(location_id,7,2)))) asa,to_number(ltrim(rtrim(substr(location_id,9,2)))) as b,to_number(ltrim(rtrim(substr(location_id,4,2)))) as Location_23_23
from location 
where location_id like '%C0S%'
and location_id not in ('C0SKRUSAGE','C0SKYUSAGE','C0SRBUSAGE') 
and to_number(ltrim(rtrim(substr(location_id,7,2)))) < 39  
and current_volume = 0  
and to_number(ltrim(rtrim(substr(location_id,9,2)))) < 17
and to_number(ltrim(rtrim(substr(location_id,4,2)))) between 23 and 23
and substr(location_id,6,1) = '-'
```

Comment: please share the DDL for locations, insert statements for the rows that cause the problem to surface, and your version of Oracle db and sql developer

Comment: Look att the following example SELECT TO_NUMBER(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTR('1234567a9',7,2)))) from dual   This will give you the same error as you have but SELECT TO_NUMBER(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTR(' 1234567a9',7,2)))) from dual will not. Could it be that you need to make your LTRIM and RTRIM before SUBSTR. like SELECT TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(LTRIM(RTRIM(' 12345678a9')),7,2)) from dual.

Answer (score 0):

this ended up solving my issue after toying with it for hours!

```
select location_id as Location_id
from location 
where location_id like '%C0S%'
and location_id not in ('C0SKRUSAGE','C0SKYUSAGE','C0SRBUSAGE') 
and ltrim(rtrim(substr(location_id,7,2))) < '48' 
and current_volume = 0 
and ltrim(rtrim(substr(location_id,9,2))) < '15'
and ltrim(rtrim(substr(location_id,4,2))) between '65' and '86'
and substr(location_id,6,1) = '-'
```

removing TO_NUMBER and adding '#' around the numbers!